# Angular change the color of a textfield when user 'leaves' it without typing anything

Tags: html, angular

Basically I've created a textfield that looks like this

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control required" [(ngModel)]="formName">
```

The CSS Class 'required' changes the background of the textfield to yellow.
My goal is to change the background color of that textfield to red whenever the user clicks inside the textfield (focus, basically want to write something inside) and leaves without typing anything (leaving it empty).

I tried to work with `[ngClass]` , something like this :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control required"  [(ngModel)]="formName" [ngClass]="{'testRed': !formName}">
```

The problem is, its red from the beginning since 'formName' is empty from the beginning, which is correct. 
Is there any smart solution without calling a function inside the .ts file?

Comment: The following link could help you: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 2):

You can define the styling for the input field in external css file by including ng-invalid to ensure that the color of text field changes when the field is invalid and include ng-touched to ensure that the color only changes when the user has touched the field atleast once. This will ensure that you don't have that changed color from the start.

```js
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    background-color : solid-red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also check for dirty state.

Lets say the form name is frmTest -

```
<input type="text" class="form-control required"
[(ngModel)]="formName"
[ngClass]="!formName && frmTest.get('formName').dirty ?? 'red' : 'yellow' ">
```